# Custom datasource for datagrid with typeconverter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

This is a followup on a question on [RichTextBoxes in a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415897/wpf-grid-cells-in-c-sharp-no-text). I've gotten pretty far but it must be converted to MVVM now. My typeconverter is not getting called so the problem is probably in my databinding. I use two datagrids to test setups quicker.

View gets a ViewModel that has the all the data.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DifferenceToTextConverter  x:Key="DifferenceToTextConverter" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="cellTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Label Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=DifferenceToTextConverter}}" >
        </Label>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

        <DataGrid Name="TestGrid" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source=DifferenceViewModel, Path=DifferenceData, Converter={StaticResource DifferenceToTextConverter}}" 
                  HeadersVisibility="Column"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource cellTemplate}" >
        </DataGrid>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid Name="OhterGrid" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=DifferenceViewModel, Path=DifferenceData}" HeadersVisibility="Column" >
            <DataGrid.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Label}">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=DifferenceToTextConverter}}" >
                    </Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.ItemTemplate>
        </DataGrid>

    public DifferenceView(ViewModel.DifferenceViewModel differenceViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DifferenceViewModel = differenceViewModel;
    }
```

ViewModel, DataTable filled with objects of my custom class. I know this has data as the method to fill it get's called. And my converter, which sits in the project root namespace

```
namespace ViewModel
{
    public class DifferenceViewModel
    {
        private DataTable differenceData;

        /// <summary>
        /// Differences between properties.
        /// </summary>
        public DataTable DifferenceData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.differenceData;
            }
            private set
            {
                this.differenceData = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

class DifferenceToTextConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type sourceType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TextBlock cell = new TextBlock();

        // Convert custom data to text representation.

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Constraints:

1. Use MVVM
2. Style in xaml when possible.
3. Text with style applied to individual letters.
4. Unknown number of columns and rows.
5. Custom typeconverter needs to construct the entire cell text.

Comment: The XAML source code you posted does not contain a XAML resource with a key named *DifferenceToTextConverter*. Also, I highly doubt that the `ItemsSource`  binding of your `DataGrid` needs that converter.

Comment: @bitbonk Added, it's simply a reference to the class with the same name. I added the extra converter to the ItemSource just to see what it would do and it din't help so you are probably right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your binding, you're not setting the DataContext correctly, no data is loaded and therefore your converter isn't being called.

Make 2 changes:
First, set your view's `DataContext` to the `DifferenceViewModel`:

```
public DifferenceView(ViewModel.DifferenceViewModel differenceViewModel)
{       
   this.DataContext = differenceViewModel;
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

Then, change your binding:
*Instead of this:*

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source=DifferenceViewModel, Path=DifferenceData, Converter={StaticResource DifferenceToTextConverter}}"
```

**Change it to this:**

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DifferenceData, Converter={StaticResource DifferenceToTextConverter}}"
```

Which basically means:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DifferenceData, Converter={StaticResource DifferenceToTextConverter}}"
```

Since your DataContext is the DifferenceViewModel, it'll directly go to the `DifferenceData` property. You can now put a breakpoint in your converter.

Comment: Thanks, now the typeconverter gets called, but the values are emtpy. I had to add a few things though. The datagrid now had both a DataSource and the ItemsSource you suggested. But a ViewModelLocator was needed to find the DifferenceViewModel. It's added through a resource reference and has a singleton reference to a DifferenceViewModel.

Comment: Couldn't really understand the problem, please post your updated code or if it's a new problem consider asking a new question